# create assembly data section for WebAssembly

Tags: clang, webassembly, llvm-ir

I have a assembly data section that i would like to compile to WebAssembly. The data section is automatically generated and the layout must match exactly in the output. This is how parts of the data looks like in GAS assembly:

```
sym_00497658_11353_5752:
.quad sym_0020ad70_3404_1468903
.quad sym_0020ada0_3404_1468951
.quad sym_00208480_3404_1458423
.byte 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
.quad sym_004a1de0_11353_48640
.global sym_00497680_11353_5792
sym_00497680_11353_5792:
.quad sym_00209e90_3404_1465095
.quad sym_0020a590_3404_1466887
.byte 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
.quad sym_004a1df0_11353_48656
.global sym_004976a0_11353_5824
...
```

Is there a way to generate such a data section for WebAssembly? I thought about using LLVM IR but im not sure how to ensure that the layout is correct.

This is part of an effort to recompile an executable to WebAssembly, this is why the section layout must match.

Comment: By layout do you mean just the part within the symbol? I am sure that's possible in LLVM IR though I don't know the specifics.

Comment: no, i mean the whole byte layout of the section, just to be sure that it is layed out correctly. i already found a solution, i will post an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang supports generating wasm objects from `.S` (preprocessed) or `.s` (not preprocessed) assembly files. I had to look at the source code of the assembly parser or LLVM to understand the syntax options...

- start the data section with this directive (the `"",@` part is needed to avoid a syntax error?):

  ```
  .section .data, "",@
  ```
- define the type of all extern symbols or functions (possible types can be found here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Target/WebAssembly/Utils/WebAssemblyTypeUtilities.cpp)

  ```
  .functype extern_func (arg1, arg2, ...) -> (return)
  .globaltype extern_global_var type
  ```
- assign a size to every defined symbol

  ```
  .global my_defined_symbol
  my_defined_symbol:
  .size my_defined_symbol, 4
  .byte ...
  ```